# Blocking export of data from Apache Superset

Tags: kubernetes-helm, apache-superset

I am integrating Apache Superset into my application, and the most important thing for me is to not allow exporting of data outside of the application (sensitive data)

I have created a custom role, started with no permissions, and added only the necessary ones.

There are a few options I have not been able to block:

- I have removed all permissions related to exporting, but when viewing Charts, I am not able to export as CSV but am able to export as JSON (which is effectively the same in terms of the data)
- Also I have been able to remove the option to share as email and get shareable like for Dashboards, but not for Charts

I have also tried to block these endpoints on an infrastructure level (Superset is running on K8S behind Nginx) but blocking the `superset-api/v1/api/*/export` does not help at all because the export through the UI is from the endpoint `superset-api/v1/api/*/data` (which cannot be blocked because it is called to view the data)